# how to solve "Some languages have errors" while publish my flutter app to Google Play Store?

Tags: flutter, publish

the problem

[image]

I've tried to change the default language or manage translation but it does not work...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately this site has rules about what questions are acceptable, and this one does not currently meet them. As a new user, you really should read [ask] to understand why a single image cannot be a correct description of the problem. Those requirements are not meant to frustrate questioners but to allow answerers to provided relevant and good quality answers. That being said, the error message is a hint that some required fields are missing in the default arabic translation...